# Что означает синтаксис foreach php

Tags: php, foreach

Почему синтаксис foreach выглядит так:

```
foreach($var1 as $var2){}
```

Для чего делается замена переменных (т.е. вместо `$var1` идет `$var2`) при обходе массива?

Comment: var1 - это сам массив, а var2 один элемент массива

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php   Почитайте основы. Потому что *$var1* это массив или объект, а *$var2* - это будет каждый отдельный элемент этого массива или объекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массив - это набор значений. Вот как например в классном журнале, список фамилий двоечников, пропускавших уроки информатики.

$var1 в твоем случае это журнал, а в $var2 при обходе массива по очереди записываются фамилии. И таким образом можно вывести на экран всех двоечников.

## Именно поэтому надо переменным давать осмысленные имена, а не var1 и var2

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach($arr AS $value)
```

Означает что цикл будет пройден по всем элементам массива. При этом каждый элемент массива будет помещен в переменную $value

Есть еще синтаксис

```
 foreach($arr AS $key => $value)
```

По смыслу аналогичен предыдущему примеру, но в этом случае накаждом шаге в переменную $key будет помещен индекс текущего элемента.

Собственно конструкция нужна для того, чтобы просмотреть все элементы массива.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` проходит по всему массиву, по идее это можно объяснить так:

1. `$var1` - массив по которому будем идти
2. делаем `reset($var1);` потом в цикле

   `while( $var2 = current($var1)){ 
      $key= key($var1);
   }`
3. чтобы этого не писать, можно просто пройти через

   `foreach($var1 as $key=>$value){}`

Удобнее не перемещать указатель как в цикле while а просто пройтись по массиву.